# How can I convert a string to a custom type so a DataGridView can write to an object of that type?

Tags: c#, datagridview, implicit-conversion

A colleague developed a set of classes to manage various types of measurements so that the unit of measurement (deg F, deg C, or whatever) can be specified at run time.  The classes have a ToString() method that returns a string containing the value and the unit, such as "100 C".

There is a class that has several members of these types.  For the purpose of this question, let's work with CSimUnitTemperature.  The class has implicit conversion operators for doubles:

```
        // Type Casting
    public static implicit operator double(SimUnitTemperature T) { return T.Temperature; }
    public static implicit operator SimUnitTemperature(double temp)
    {
        SimUnitTemperature T = new SimUnitTemperature();
        T.Temperature = temp;
        return T;
    }
```

The CSimRecipeSegment class has several members of type SimUnitTemperature.  I can create a List object and use it as a data source for a DataGridView.  But when I try to change a value shown as "100 C" to "110 C", I get a long exception message beginning with "Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'SimShopMeasures.SimUnitTemperature'.

So, I tried to provide an implicit conversion from a string to a SimUnitTmeperature object, using a little string extension method I wrote that converts the first piece of a string into a double:

```
        public static implicit operator string(SimUnitTemperature T)
    {
        return T.ToString();
    }
    public static implicit operator SimUnitTemperature(string tempString)
    {
        SimUnitTemperature T = new SimUnitTemperature();
        T.Temperature = tempString.FirstValue();
        return T;
    }
```

But when I tried to use this, I got the same exception.  Breakpoints on both of these methods were not hit when I tried to change a value in the DataGridView.

I know I can add public properties of type double to the class that is using all these temperatures, and that's probably what I'll do, but I think it would be cleaner to change the SimUnitTemperature class to let me do this.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried using the [CellParsing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellparsing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event to trap the entry and deal with it?

Comment: Never having done this I could be wrong, but I think you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on SimUnitTemperature. Here's an example: http://tech.pro/tutorial/776/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-collection.

Comment: Thank you for telling me about the CellParsing event.  That looks very helpful.  However, I would still like to know how to modify the CSimUnitTemperature class so that it's not necessary to modify every DataGridView I use to display my obects.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.  I don't think it will be an answer to my original question, although I am sure I will be implementing it soon to get all of the behavior I want from my DataGridView.